# how can I display an Applet in my JTextPane

Tags: java, html, swing, applet, jtextpane

I have a html file that contains an applet to draw an image,I tried to display it in my JTextPane,but when I compile,the jTextPane displays only the applet tag and not the image,and when I execute the file html with the navigator it works fine,this is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 

JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
  JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane();
  js.getViewport().add(tp);
  JFrame jf = new JFrame();
  jf.getContentPane().add(js);
  jf.pack();
  jf.setVisible(true); 
  tp.setPage("file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/USER/Thomson/NetBeansProjects/testapp/src/testapp.html");


  }
}
```

I don't know where is the problem in my code can some one help me and thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `applet` tag is not supported by [HTMLEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html).

EDIT:

JTextPane has very limited HTML support. I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but you could try using an embedded browser, ie [jbrowser](http://code.google.com/p/jbrowser/).

Comment: This answers why the OP's code is not working, but not how he could get it to work.

Comment: It does mention "... but some support is provided for the <object> tag.". You can give that a try

Comment: An `Applet` is a subclass of `Component`, so you can add that directly to your GUI layout (if that's an acceptable solution).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to do this is to simply add the `Applet` to your layout (with proper `AppletStub` fill-in if needed) and if anything else is needed around the `Applet`'s panel, add it with `JLabel`s.